# HttpWebResponse shows junk characters in Headers C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebresponse

Here is the code snippet that returns a persian language word in `Response.AddHeaders`

[image: farsi text]

and here is a code snippert that get response via `HttpWebResponse` and shows junk characters for that persian word

[image: junk text]

I'm curious why does it returns these garbage characters? And how i can rectify this issue? On my aspx page the junk text appears like this-

[image: output text]

Please help as soon as possible...

Thanks

Comment: I hope you are using SSL - Password in a header WOW !

Comment: and suppose it is not a password. What i should do in case of a non-password field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found unicode encoding useful.

```
pwd = HttpUtility.UrlEncodeUnicode(pwd); // encode string to unicode

pwd = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(pwd); // decode unicode to string
```